# Coloring lines in a Bokeh Plot

Tags: python, plot, colors, bokeh, line-plot

I have a Bokeh App that contains a Line Plot. This plot has 10 lines in it. How do I color the lines with different shades of the same color?

Is there any way I can generate a list of different shades of the same color without hardcoding it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a palette from bokeh.palettes:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.palettes import Blues9

output_file('palette.html')

p = figure()
p.scatter(x=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], y=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], radius=1, fill_color=Blues9)

show(p)
```

[image: Palette Example]

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/palettes.html

Comment: I just came across this! Thanks! I have 10 lines. Can't find 2 Palettes which give me 10 colors each. Like, the ones with a contrast (E.g. Greens9 and OrRd9)

Comment: FYI, I've marked your response as the answer but it's just doesn't show due to my low reputation.